# How to display text with different colors in mode-line

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

I want to display parts of my mode line with different colors but it isn't working as expected and I can't find a good web reference for this. I can change the text to bold or italic but not change the colors as required.

The simplest possible example is to display a simple mode line with the **buffer-file-name** in white rather than the default face color.

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(mode-line-format
   (quote
    ("%e" mode-line-front-space
     "[" mode-name "] %l:%i"
     "\t"
     propertize buffer-file-name 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "white")))))
```

Thanks to legosica for pointing out that I should have included other examples of what I've tried ...

1. Replacing 'font-lock-face with 'face:

   ```
   propertize buffer-file-name 'face '(:foreground "white")))))
   ```

#### Follow Up

Thanks to TacticalCoder I now have exactly what I want - multiple fonts and colours in my modeline.  The reason why setting `'face '(:foreground "white")` didn't work is that it needed to be wrapped in '(:eval ...).

I ended up with this ...

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
  (list

    mode-line-front-space ; +-- just like in the default mode-line-format

    '(:eval (propertize (concat "\t[" mode-name "] %l:%i\t") 'face '(:foreground "black" :height 0.9 :weight normal)
        'help-echo (buffer-file-name)))

    '(:eval (propertize (file-name-directory buffer-file-name)  'face 'info-title-4
        'help-echo (buffer-file-name)))

    '(:eval (propertize (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)  'face 'info-title-3
        'help-echo (buffer-file-name)))

    ))
```

Combined with ...

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(info-title-3 ((t (:inherit info-title-4 :foreground "white" :height 1.2))))
 '(info-title-4 ((t (:inherit info-title-4 :foreground "black"))))
 '(mode-line ((t (:background "#6483af" :foreground "#001122" :box (:line-width 3 :color "#6483af") :weight ultra-bold :height 118 :family "Monospace")))))
```

... I get a nice simple mode-line that demonstrates most of what I want. More work to do but thanks to TacticalCoder, I'm back on track.

Comment: Could you try `'face` instead of `'font-lock-face`?

Comment: @legoscia Thanks, I had tried that already. I think I've lost track of all of the things I've tried :-(

Comment: See https://github.com/jonathanchu/emacs-powerline for reference.

Comment: @abo-abo Thanks but my Lisp isn't good enough to follow the implementation of powerline. Can you point me to a part that might be close to what I need?

Comment: google for `mode-line-format colors` in google-images and you will find many examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tiny part of the custom modeline I'm using (I don't remember where I found it), modified as you asked to show the buffer name in another color. In this example I'm using `font-lock-warning-face` (which is 'red' in my color scheme):

This is not a complete modeline by any mean:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
  (list

    mode-line-front-space ; +-- just like in the default mode-line-format
    mode-line-mule-info   ; |
    mode-line-client      ; |

    ;; the buffer name; the file name as a tool tip if you hover the mouse on it
    '(:eval (propertize "%b " 'face 'font-lock-warning-face
        'help-echo (buffer-file-name)))

    '(:eval (propertize (if overwrite-mode "OVERWRITE" "")
              'face 'font-lock-warning-face
              'help-echo (concat "Buffer is in "
                           (if overwrite-mode "overwrite" "insert") " mode")))

    "%-"                  ; fill what's left with '-'
    ))
```

Does that work for you? I did also put the part where OVERWRITE appears in `font-lock-warning-face` in case you turn overwrite on (I kinda hate being in overwrite mode, so I want it to be very obvious).

Comment: I'm voting you up for this and when I get a chance to check it out I may will accept this as the correct answer. It also shows some things that I wanted to do next so thumbs up for that!

Comment: @ChrisMcCauley: I'll add some more then, there's something you might want to do... By the way, you can simply try to eval the function I wrote and see instantly if it works or not.

Comment: You could be getting a lot of upvotes for this. I could have simply used powerline or one of the other tools but then I wouldn't learn anything. I'm sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: @ChrisMcCauley: ah forget it: it's actually the exact same mechanism as the one used for "overwrite", but applied to other things... So basically you sould be good to go : )