# How to colorize some text in the mode-line differently

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces, modeline

Is it possible to have *some* part of the mode line colored differently occasionally?

I know how to [change the entire line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15906332/772868) but I would like to color just a part of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24862563/1030675